# how to seperate alphabets and numbers from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

Array Input as

```
var a =[1,'a',2,3,'e',4,'r'];
```

I have tried to convert this array to string and by checking the length of the string as below

I want to convert the array to

```
    ['a','e','r',1,2,3,4]
```

Is this a correct way of doing?

```js
var a = [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'e', 4, 'r'];
var b = a.toString();
console.log(b);
var num, alpha;
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  var letters = /[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var numbers = /[0-9]/;
  if (b.charAt(i).match(numbers))
    num.append(b.charAt(i));
  else if (b.charAt(i).match(letters))
    alpha.append(b.charAt(i));
}

console.log(alpha);
console.log(num);
```

Comment: should it be just separated or sorted by type as well?

Comment: You can try to sort by its ascii code.

Comment: .append is not correct javascript. You need push

Comment: Just use a filter or map

Comment: @valli - Do you want to sort as well? i.e. if input is `array = [4, 'a', 2, 3, 'r', 1, 'e'];`  then result should be `['a', 'r', 'e', 4, 2, 3, 1]` or `['a', 'e', 'r', 1, 2 , 3, 4]`?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Yes,I want to sort as well if numbers were given randomly

Answer (score 4):

You could sort the array by taking the delta of the check for number.

```js
var array = [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'e', 4, 'r'];

array.sort((a, b) => (typeof a === 'number') - (typeof b === 'number'));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: You are the legendary.

Comment: Even more succinctly :  `array.sort((a, b) => (+a === +a) - (+b === +b));
`

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follow:

```js
var a =[1,'a',2,3,'e',4,'r'];
var a_word = [];
var a_number = [];
a.forEach(current=>{
  if(typeof(current)==="number")
    a_number.push(current);
  if(typeof(current)==="string")
    a_word.push(current);
});
var result = a_word.concat(a_number);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Filter sounds like a good choice

```js
var a =[1,'a',2,3,'e',4,'r'];

var newArr = [];
var num = a.filter(function(num) {
  if (isNaN(num)) newArr.push(num)
  return !isNaN(+num)
});
console.log([...newArr,...num]); // create a new array
newArr = newArr.concat(num); // or reuse
console.log(newArr)

// or just

console.log(a.sort()); // will sort numbers first
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this:

```js
const a = [ 1, 'a', 2, 3, 'e', 4, 'r' ]

const b = a.reduce( ( acc, item ) => {
  if ( typeof item == 'number' ) {
    acc.push( item )
  } else {
    acc.unshift( item )
  }
  return acc
}, [] ).sort( ( a, b ) => a > b )

console.log( b )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following using [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
let a =[1,'a',2,3,'e',4,'r'];
a.sort((b,c) => isNaN(c) - isNaN(b) || String(b).localeCompare(String(c)))
console.log(a);
```